# Arc4random modulo biased

Tags: objective-c, random, probability, arc4random

According to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/arc4random.3.html),

> `arc4random_uniform()` is recommended over constructions like `arc4random() % upper_bound` as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

How bad is the bias? For example if I generate random numbers with an upper bound of 6, what's the difference between using `arc4random` with `%` and `arc4random_uniform()`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

arc4random() returns an unsigned 32-bit integer, meaning the values are between
0 and 2^32-1 = 4 294 967 295.

Now, the bias results from the fact that the multiple subintervals created with
modulo are not fitting exactly into the random output range.
Lets imagine for clarity a random generator that creates numbers from 0 to 198
inclusive. You want numbers from 0 to 99, therefore you calculate random() % 100,
yielding 0 to 99:

0   % 100 = 0
99  % 100 = 99
100 % 100 = 0
198 % 100 = 98

You see that 99 is the only number which can occur only *once* while all
others can occur *twice* in a run. That means that the probability for 99
is exactly halved which is also the worst case in a bias where at least
2 subintervals are involved.
As all powers of two smaller than the range interval fits nicely into the
2^32 interval, the bias disappears in this case.

The implications are that the smaller the result set with modulo and the higher
the random output range, the smaller the bias. In your example, 6 is your upper
bound (I assume 0 is the lower bound), so you use % 7, resulting that 0-3
occurs 613 566 757 times while 4-6 occurs 613 566 756 times.
So 0-3 is 613 566 757 / 613 566 756 = 1.0000000016298 times more probable
than 4-6.

While it seems easy to dismiss, some experiments (especially Monte-Carlo
experiments) were flawed exactly because these seemingly incredible small
differences were pretty important.

Even worse is the bias if the desired output range is *bigger* than
the random target range. Please read the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) entry
because many poker sites learned the hard way that normal linear
congruential random generators and bad shuffling algorithms resulted in
impossible or very probable decks or worse, *predictable* decks.

Comment: Excellent explanation of the problem. Readers may also be interested in the implementation, which is publicly available: http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c It is true that in many applications the bias does not matter, but it is so devastating in cases where it *does* matter that programmers should always be in the habit of using `_uniform`.

Comment: How does one avoid the bias?

Comment: @android, by shrinking your selection range to something a multiple of what you want, and then rolling random numbers until you are inside the range. If you want a random number 1-4 from a six-sided dice, the correct way to get it is to roll it until the number is between 1 and 4. Same principle.

Comment: The easiest way is to rerun the random generator when the "forbidden" range is entered. e.g. do { result = arc4random() % 7 } while (result > 4 294 967 292).