# How to generate a random number in Swift?

Tags: swift, random

I realize the Swift book provided an implementation of a random number generator.  Is the best practice to copy and paste this implementation? Or is there a library that does this that we can use now?

Answer (score 675, accepted):

**Swift 4.2+**

Swift 4.2 shipped with Xcode 10 introduces new easy-to-use random functions for many data types.

You simply call the `random()` method on numeric types.

```
let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<6)
let randomDouble = Double.random(in: 2.71828...3.14159)
let randomBool = Bool.random()
```

Comment: I didn't have to explicitly import Darwin

Comment: In my Playground file I needed to import Darwin because I wasn't importing anything else.

Comment: SoliQuiD: except omit the extra underscore after arc4, i.e. arc4random_uniform(5).

Comment: **Warning**: RC4 or arc4 [has been shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Biased_outputs_of_the_RC4) to be [distinguishable from pure random values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguishing_attack). So although arc4 (a stream cipher) *sounds* cryptographically secure, it actually isn't.

Comment: `Float.random(in: 0...1)` for values between 0 and 1 (or `Double.random` if you want double precision)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: no longer directly relevant to this answer, but arc4random does not actually use the RC4 cipher, despite its name, on macOS or the BSDs. It uses a system-provided CSPRNG on macOS, and ChaCha20 on most BSDs. Swift's default RNG (as used in this answer) calls it as an implementation detail on macOS, but uses an appropriate underlying generator on each supported platform.

Comment: Ah, wow. The correct way of dealing with that is making the function deprecated of course. I guess they need it for backwards compatibility, but it definitely fails the principle of least surprise :) Thanks for the comment, highly appreciated.

Comment: Or `let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0...5)` The difference between `...` and `..<` is that the first one `...` includes the upper boundary while the second one `..<` excludes it

Comment: Perfect for Bool.random()

Answer (score 500):

Use `arc4random_uniform(n)` for a random integer between 0 and n-1.

```
let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1)
```

Cast the result to Int so you don't have to explicitly type your vars as `UInt32` (which seems un-Swifty).

Comment: Very simple. I like it. Upvote! But an actual dice doesn't have `0`. In your code, `diceRoll` could be `0`. Just saying...

Comment: Yeah, you really want `Int(arc4random_uniform(6)+1)`.

Comment: probability = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(total))) – i also had to cast into UInt32

Comment: let randomElementInArray = Int(arc4random_uniform(array.count))

Comment: Don't forget to cast the parameter, n, entered into `arc3random_uniform(n)` to a `UInt32(n)` if you are using a value that isn't already of that type.

Comment: what does the '6' in arc4random_uniform(6) represent?

Comment: and how would i write a random number between 5 and 15?

Comment: @OrenEdrich the "6" functions as a boundary. in the solution above your will get a random number between 0 and the boundary minus 1 (n-1). So 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. To get a random number between 5 and 15 see the answer below that includes an upper  bounds and a lower bounds.

Comment: The code above has a bias, and the distribution is not uniform.

Answer (score 116):

**Edit:** [Updated for Swift 3.0](https://gist.github.com/jstn/f9d5437316879c9c448a)

`arc4random` works well in Swift, but the base functions are limited to 32-bit integer types (`Int` is 64-bit on iPhone 5S and modern Macs). Here's a generic function for a random number of a type expressible by an integer literal:

```
public func arc4random<T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>(_ type: T.Type) -> T {
    var r: T = 0
    arc4random_buf(&r, MemoryLayout<T>.size)
    return r
}
```

We can use this new generic function to extend `UInt64`, adding boundary arguments and mitigating modulo bias. (This is lifted straight from [arc4random.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-997.90.3/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c))

```
public extension UInt64 {
    public static func random(lower: UInt64 = min, upper: UInt64 = max) -> UInt64 {
        var m: UInt64
        let u = upper - lower
        var r = arc4random(UInt64.self)

        if u > UInt64(Int64.max) {
            m = 1 + ~u
        } else {
            m = ((max - (u * 2)) + 1) % u
        }

        while r < m {
            r = arc4random(UInt64.self)
        }

        return (r % u) + lower
    }
}
```

With that we can extend `Int64` for the same arguments, dealing with overflow:

```
public extension Int64 {
    public static func random(lower: Int64 = min, upper: Int64 = max) -> Int64 {
        let (s, overflow) = Int64.subtractWithOverflow(upper, lower)
        let u = overflow ? UInt64.max - UInt64(~s) : UInt64(s)
        let r = UInt64.random(upper: u)

        if r > UInt64(Int64.max)  {
            return Int64(r - (UInt64(~lower) + 1))
        } else {
            return Int64(r) + lower
        }
    }
}
```

To complete the family...

```
private let _wordSize = __WORDSIZE

public extension UInt32 {
    public static func random(lower: UInt32 = min, upper: UInt32 = max) -> UInt32 {
        return arc4random_uniform(upper - lower) + lower
    }
}

public extension Int32 {
    public static func random(lower: Int32 = min, upper: Int32 = max) -> Int32 {
        let r = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Int64(upper) - Int64(lower)))
        return Int32(Int64(r) + Int64(lower))
    }
}

public extension UInt {
    public static func random(lower: UInt = min, upper: UInt = max) -> UInt {
        switch (_wordSize) {
            case 32: return UInt(UInt32.random(UInt32(lower), upper: UInt32(upper)))
            case 64: return UInt(UInt64.random(UInt64(lower), upper: UInt64(upper)))
            default: return lower
        }
    }
}

public extension Int {
    public static func random(lower: Int = min, upper: Int = max) -> Int {
        switch (_wordSize) {
            case 32: return Int(Int32.random(Int32(lower), upper: Int32(upper)))
            case 64: return Int(Int64.random(Int64(lower), upper: Int64(upper)))
            default: return lower
        }
    }
}
```

After all that, we can finally do something like this:

```
let diceRoll = UInt64.random(lower: 1, upper: 7)
```

Comment: It does not compile: `var r = arc4random(UInt64)`. Please advice what did you mean here?

Comment: @Ossir compiles fine for me... it means call the function `arc4random` (defined in the first code block) with the argument `UInt64` which is a `Type`.

Comment: Does arc4random_buf (and therefore all of the 64-bit extensions) suffer from modulo bias?

Comment: Modulo bias only comes into play when you add an upper bound, so it doesn't apply to `arc4random_buf`. The purpose of these extensions is to do exactly what `arc4random_uniform` does (mitigate modulo bias) except for 64-bit types.

Comment: when using the float functions, how can I include the upper value in the range of possibilities? So lets say I do 0.0 as the lower and 1.0 as the upper. With this logic it will give me 0.0 up to 0.99999999. But instead I'd like to include the 1.0 as a possibility. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for this. What is the '~' doing in this syntax ? So for instance what is going on here UInt64(~lower) ?

Comment: The `~` operator is `bitwise NOT`. It's a quick way to get the ones' complement of an integer, which behaves like its negative in this context. The overall strategy here is to get an unsigned random integer and fit it into a signed integer range; which is fine but we have to be careful with the overflow when we subtract. The Swift documentation on advanced operators has an excellent explanation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html

Comment: Swift 4 complaint on Int64.subtractWithOverflow

Comment: Can you mathematically prove `arc4random_buf` produces uniform numbers of type `T`?

Answer (score 95):

**Edit for Swift 4.2**

Starting in Swift 4.2, instead of using the imported C function arc4random_uniform(), you can now use Swift’s own native functions.

```
// Generates integers starting with 0 up to, and including, 10
Int.random(in: 0 ... 10)
```

You can use `random(in:)` to get random values for other primitive values as well; such as Int, Double, Float and even Bool.

**Swift versions < 4.2**

This method will generate a random `Int` value between the given minimum and maximum

```
func randomInt(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
}
```

Answer (score 59):

I used this code:

```
var k: Int = random() % 10;
```

Comment: you must call srandom(UInt32(time(nil))) first, otherwise it will always return the same number sequence

Comment: first means in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: I read the apple doc on random() twice but could not glean its usage... I wish they simply included a simply code sample like this on above.  

"The random() function uses a non-linear, additive feedback, random number generator, employing a
     default table of size 31 long integers.  It returns successive pseudo-random numbers in the range from
     0 to (2**31)-1.  The period of this random number generator is very large, approximately
     16*((2**31)-1)." ... Thanks a lot apple... I'll be sure to reference this in my next thesis.

Comment: random() sometimes leads to a sudden crash on iPads. If this happens, use the  arc4random_uniform(6) from above. If you use random() then you can create more random values by prepending srandomdev().

Comment: I got compiler error message: `random is unavailable in Swift: Use arc4random instead.`

Comment: This solution has modulo bias: https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/generating-random-numbers-without-modulo-bias/

Answer (score 33):

As of iOS 9, you can use the new GameplayKit classes to generate random numbers in a variety of ways.

You have four source types to choose from: a general random source (unnamed, down to the system to choose what it does), linear congruential, ARC4 and Mersenne Twister. These can generate random ints, floats and bools.

At the simplest level, you can generate a random number from the system's built-in random source like this:

```
GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt()
```

That generates a number between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647. If you want a number between 0 and an upper bound (exclusive) you'd use this:

```
GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(6)
```

GameplayKit has some convenience constructors built in to work with dice. For example, you can roll a six-sided die like this:

```
let d6 = GKRandomDistribution.d6()
d6.nextInt()
```

Plus you can shape the random distribution by using things like GKShuffledDistribution. That takes a little more explaining, but if you're interested you can [read my tutorial on GameplayKit random numbers](http://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/35/overview).

Comment: Thanks for this tip, it is one of best answers. To use these functions one needs to add `import GameplayKit`. Swift 3 changed the syntax to `GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 6)`

Comment: how heavy is this kit to import?  i don't want to bloat my code.

Answer (score 24):

You can do it the same way that you would in C:

```
let randomNumber = arc4random()
```

`randomNumber` is inferred to be of type `UInt32` (a 32-bit unsigned integer)

Comment: Addendum: `rand`, `arc4random`, `drand48` and friends are all in the `Darwin` module. It's already imported for you if you're building a Cocoa, UIKit, or Foundation app, but you'll need to `import Darwin` in playgrounds.

Comment: And don't attempt to cast the result of arc4random() to an Int — this will work fine on a 64-bit platform, but on a 32-bit platform, Ints are 32-bit signed, so you'll get unexpected negative numbers. This has tripped a few people up already, so I figured I'd mention it here.

Answer (score 23):

## Use `arc4random_uniform()`

**Usage:**

`arc4random_uniform(someNumber: UInt32) -> UInt32`

This gives you random integers in the range `0` to `someNumber - 1`.

The maximum value for `UInt32` is 4,294,967,295 (that is, `2^32 - 1`).

**Examples:**

- Coin flip

  ```
    let flip = arc4random_uniform(2) // 0 or 1
  ```
- Dice roll

  ```
    let roll = arc4random_uniform(6) + 1 // 1...6
  ```
- Random day in October

  ```
    let day = arc4random_uniform(31) + 1 // 1...31
  ```
- Random year in the 1990s

  ```
    let year = 1990 + arc4random_uniform(10)
  ```

**General form:**

```
let number = min + arc4random_uniform(max - min + 1)
```

where `number`, `max`, and `min` are `UInt32`.

## What about...

**arc4random()**

You can also get a random number by using `arc4random()`, which produces a `UInt32` between 0 and 2^32-1. Thus to get a random number between `0` and `x-1`, you can divide it by `x` and take the remainder. Or in other words, use the [Remainder Operator (%)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

```
let number = arc4random() % 5 // 0...4
```

However, this produces the slight [modulo bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956021/3681880) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17640956/3681880)), so that is why `arc4random_uniform()` is recommended.

**Converting to and from `Int`**

Normally it would be fine to do something like this in order to convert back and forth between `Int` and `UInt32`:

```
let number: Int = 10
let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(number)))
```

The problem, though, is that [`Int`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) has a range of `-2,147,483,648...2,147,483,647` on 32 bit systems and a range of `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808...9,223,372,036,854,775,807` on 64 bit systems. Compare this to the `UInt32` range of `0...4,294,967,295`. The `U` of `UInt32` means *unsigned*.

Consider the following errors:

```
UInt32(-1) // negative numbers cause integer overflow error
UInt32(4294967296) // numbers greater than 4,294,967,295 cause integer overflow error
```

So you just need to be sure that your input parameters are within the `UInt32` range and that you don't need an output that is outside of that range either.

Answer (score 20):

Example for random number in between 10 (0-9);

```
import UIKit

let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
```

Very easy code - simple and short.

Answer (score 17):

I've been able to just use `rand()` to get a random CInt. You can make it an Int by using something like this:

```
let myVar: Int = Int(rand())
```

You can use your favourite C random function, and just convert to value to Int if needed.

Comment: Yep, type conversion can be a tricky business otherwise and letting the Int constructor deal with it is real pain saver.

Comment: Note that if you're not calling srand(...) (call it once only) before using rand(), the sequence of numbers will always be exactly the same between each execution of your program. If you don't want this then use arc4random()

Comment: You could also used `random()`, which returns an `Int` rather than `UInt32` -- and like @SomeGuy mentioned, simply call `srandom(arc4random())` once anywhere before using it to ensure it has a different, randomized seed for each execution of your program.

Comment: Can anyone comment on rand() vs arc4random_uniform()?

Answer (score 17):

[@jstn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25129039/6107425) is good, but a bit verbose. Swift is known as a protocol-oriented language, so we can achieve the same result without having to implement boilerplate code for every class in the integer family, by adding a default implementation for the protocol extension.

```
public extension ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    public static func arc4random() -> Self {
        var r: Self = 0
        arc4random_buf(&r, MemoryLayout<Self>.size)
        return r
    }
}
```

Now we can do:

```
let i = Int.arc4random()
let j = UInt32.arc4random()
```

and all other integer classes are ok.

Answer (score 14):

**Updated**: June 09, 2022.

### Swift 5.7

Let's assume we have an array:

```
let numbers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

For iOS and macOS you can use **system-wide random source** in Xcode's framework `GameKit`. Here you can find `GKRandomSource` class with its `sharedRandom()` class method:

```
import GameKit

private func randomNumberGenerator() -> Int {
    let rand = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: numbers.count)
    return numbers[rand]
}

randomNumberGenerator()
```

Also you can use a `randomElement()` method that returns a random element of a collection:

```
let randomNumber = numbers.randomElement()!
print(randomNumber)
```

Or use `arc4random_uniform()`. Pay attention that this method returns `UInt32` type.

```
let generator = Int(arc4random_uniform(11))
print(generator)
```

And, of course, we can use a `makeIterator()` method that returns an iterator over the elements of the collection.

```
let iterator: Int = (1...10).makeIterator().shuffled().first!
print(iterator)
```

The final example you see here returns a random value within the specified range with a help of `static func random(in range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int`.

```
let randomizer = Int.random(in: 1...10)
print(randomizer)
```

Pseudo-random Double number generator `drand48()` returns a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
import Foundation

let randomInt = Int(drand48() * 10)
```

Answer (score 13):

In **Swift 4.2** you can generate random numbers by calling the `random()` method on whatever numeric type you want, providing the range you want to work with. For example, this generates a random number in the range 1 through 9, inclusive on both sides

```
let randInt = Int.random(in: 1..<10)
```

Also with other types

```
let randFloat = Float.random(in: 1..<20)
let randDouble = Double.random(in: 1...30)
let randCGFloat = CGFloat.random(in: 1...40)
```

Answer (score 11):

## Since *Swift 4.2*

There is a new set of APIs:

```
let randomIntFrom0To10 = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10)
let randomDouble = Double.random(in: 1 ... 10)
```

- All **numeric** types now have the [`random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/2995514-random) method that takes `range`.
- It returns a number uniformly distributed in that range.

---

**TL;DR**

#### Well, what is wrong with the "good" old way?

1. You have to use imported *C* APIs *(They are different between platforms)*.
2. And moreover...

> *What if I told you that the random is not that random?*

If you use `arc4random()` *(to calculate the remainder)* like `arc4random() % aNumber`, the result **is not** uniformly distributed between the `0` and `aNumber`. There is a problem called the **Modulo bias**.

**Modulo bias**

Normally, the function generates a random number between `0` and *MAX* *(depends on the type etc.)*. To make a quick, easy example, let's say the max number is `7` and you care about a random number in the range `0 ..< 2` *(or the interval [0, 3) if you prefer that)*.

The **probabilities** for individual numbers are:

- *0: 3/8 = 37.5%*
- *1: 3/8 = 37.5%*
- *2: 2/8 = 25%*

In other words, you are **more likely** to end up with *0* or *1* than *2*. 
 Of course, bare in mind that this is extremely simplified and the *MAX* number is much higher, making it more "fair".

> This problem is addressed by [SE-0202 - Random unification](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md) in *Swift 4.2*

Comment: an excellent answer

Answer (score 9):

Here is a library that does the job well
https://github.com/thellimist/SwiftRandom

```
public extension Int {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random(lower: Int = 0, _ upper: Int = 100) -> Int {
        return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
    }
}

public extension Double {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random(lower: Double = 0, _ upper: Double = 100) -> Double {
        return (Double(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (upper - lower) + lower
    }
}

public extension Float {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random(lower: Float = 0, _ upper: Float = 100) -> Float {
        return (Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (upper - lower) + lower
    }
}

public extension CGFloat {
    /// SwiftRandom extension
    public static func random(lower: CGFloat = 0, _ upper: CGFloat = 1) -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)) * (upper - lower) + lower
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 let MAX : UInt32 = 9
 let MIN : UInt32 = 1

    func randomNumber()
{
    var random_number = Int(arc4random_uniform(MAX) + MIN)
    print ("random = ", random_number);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Update

My original comments below may be of historical interest, but the answer ever since Swift 4.2 the correct answer is to use [random(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/random(in:)-3uaq4).

### Original comments

I would like to add to existing answers that the random number generator example in the Swift book is a Linear Congruence Generator (LCG), it is a severely limited one and shouldn't be except for the must trivial examples, where quality of randomness doesn't matter at all. And **a LCG should never be used for cryptographic purposes**.

`arc4random()` is much better and can be used for most purposes, but again **should not be used for cryptographic purposes.**

If you want something that is guaranteed to be cryptographically secure, use `SecCopyRandomBytes()`.  Note that if you build a random number generator into something, someone else might end up (mis)-using it for cryptographic purposes (such as password, key or salt generation), then you should consider using `SecCopyRandomBytes()` anyway, even if your need doesn't quite require that.

Comment: But how do I generate a random number in range using `SecCopyRandomBytes()`? How to generate a secure random number between 0 and 128, for example?

Comment: @acmpu6ou, just use `random(in:)`. Much of the discussion you see here, including my original comment, is about working around the fact that Swift did not at the time provide a nice way of handing this. That has long since been remedied.

Answer (score 6):

```
var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(5)))
```

Here 5 will make sure that the random number is generated through zero to four. You can set the value accordingly.

Comment: If you pass 5 it will return 5 possible results from zero to four. 0...4

Comment: For anyone googling here this is extremely out of date, don't use

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2**

Bye bye to import Foundation C lib  `arc4random_uniform()`

```
// 1  
let digit = Int.random(in: 0..<10)

// 2
if let anotherDigit = (0..<10).randomElement() {
  print(anotherDigit)
} else {
  print("Empty range.")
}

// 3
let double = Double.random(in: 0..<1)
let float = Float.random(in: 0..<1)
let cgFloat = CGFloat.random(in: 0..<1)
let bool = Bool.random()
```

1. You use random(in:) to generate random digits from ranges.
2. randomElement() returns nil if the range is empty, so you unwrap the returned Int? with if let.
3. You use random(in:) to generate a random Double, Float or CGFloat and random() to return a random Bool.

[More @ Official](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md)

Answer (score 5):

Without arc4Random_uniform() in some versions of Xcode(in 7.1 it runs but doesn't autocomplete for me). You can do this instead.

To generate a random number from 0-5.
First

```
import GameplayKit
```

Then

```
let diceRoll = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(6)
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code will produce a secure random number between 0 and 255:

```
extension UInt8 {
  public static var random: UInt8 {
    var number: UInt8 = 0
    _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &number)
    return number
  }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
print(UInt8.random)
```

For bigger numbers it becomes more complicated.
This is the best I could come up with:

```
extension UInt16 {
  public static var random: UInt16 {
    let count = Int(UInt8.random % 2) + 1
    var numbers = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 2)
    _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, count, &numbers)
    return numbers.reversed().reduce(0) { $0 << 8 + UInt16($1) }
  }
}

extension UInt32 {
  public static var random: UInt32 {
    let count = Int(UInt8.random % 4) + 1
    var numbers = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
    _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, count, &numbers)
    return numbers.reversed().reduce(0) { $0 << 8 + UInt32($1) }
  }
}
```

These methods use an extra random number to determine how many `UInt8`s are going to be used to create the random number. The last line converts the `[UInt8]` to `UInt16` or `UInt32`.

I don't know if the last two still count as truly random, but you can tweak it to your likings :)

Comment: You cleverly avoided the bias introduced by modulo, ＋1 for that. You might warn readers why you did it.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't really consider that modulo bias might be in play here. Perhaps the chances of getting a small number aren't the same as getting a large number.

Comment: But how do I specify my own range? What if I need to generate a number between 0 and 56, for example? Also, I think you shouldn't ignore the returned value from `SecRandomCopyBytes`.

Comment: Here is an answer to my question if anyone's interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76722087/11004423

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

Swift 4.2 has included a native and fairly full-featured random number API in the standard library. ([Swift Evolution proposal SE-0202](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0202-random-unification.md))

```
let intBetween0to9 = Int.random(in: 0...9) 
let doubleBetween0to1 = Double.random(in: 0...1)
```

All number types have the static [random(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger/2995514-random) which takes the range and returns the random number in the given range

Answer (score 2):

**Xcode 14, swift 5**

```
public extension Array where Element == Int {
    static func generateNonRepeatedRandom(size: Int) -> [Int] {
        guard size > 0 else {
            return [Int]()
        }
        return Array(0..<size).shuffled()
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
let array = Array.generateNonRepeatedRandom(size: 15)
print(array)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GeneratorOf` like this:

```
var fibs = ArraySlice([1, 1])
var fibGenerator = GeneratorOf{
    _ -> Int? in
    fibs.append(fibs.reduce(0, combine:+))
    return fibs.removeAtIndex(0)
}

println(fibGenerator.next())
println(fibGenerator.next())
println(fibGenerator.next())
println(fibGenerator.next())
println(fibGenerator.next())
println(fibGenerator.next())
```

Comment: How's Fibonacci random?

Comment: Hi Nikolai, This code block is old version Swift 1.2. If you try new Swift 2.0. It wouldn't be work.

Comment: I understand, but still it looks like a fibonacci generator to me, not random numbers, like asked for in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to generate a random number:

```
//
//  FactModel.swift
//  Collection
//
//  Created by Ahmadreza Shamimi on 6/11/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Ahmadreza Shamimi. All rights reserved.
//

import GameKit

struct FactModel {

    let fun  = ["I love swift","My name is Ahmadreza","I love coding" ,"I love PHP","My name is ALireza","I love Coding too"]


    func getRandomNumber() -> String {

        let randomNumber  = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(fun.count)

        return fun[randomNumber]
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code only answers are discouraged - please edit your answer to explain why this code answers the question, and how it works. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more information.

Comment: Please provide some context around your answer, and welcome to stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score -1):

### Details

xCode 9.1, Swift 4

### Math oriented solution (1)

```
import Foundation

class Random {

    subscript<T>(_ min: T, _ max: T) -> T where T : BinaryInteger {
        get {
            return rand(min-1, max+1)
        }
    }
}

let rand = Random()

func rand<T>(_ min: T, _ max: T) -> T where T : BinaryInteger {
    let _min = min + 1
    let difference = max - _min
    return T(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(difference))) + _min
}
```

### Usage of solution (1)

```
let x = rand(-5, 5)       // x = [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
let x = rand[0, 10]       // x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

### Programmers oriented solution (2)

> Do not forget to **add Math oriented solution (1) code** here

```
import Foundation

extension CountableRange where Bound : BinaryInteger {

    var random: Bound {
        return rand(lowerBound-1, upperBound)
    }
}

extension CountableClosedRange where Bound : BinaryInteger {

    var random: Bound {
        return rand[lowerBound, upperBound]
    }
}
```

### Usage of solution (2)

```
let x = (-8..<2).random           // x = [-8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1]
let x = (0..<10).random           // x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let x = (-10 ... -2).random       // x = [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2]
```

### Full Sample

> Do not forget to **add solution (1) and solution (2) codes** here

```
private func generateRandNums(closure:()->(Int)) {

    var allNums = Set<Int>()
    for _ in 0..<100 {
        allNums.insert(closure())
    }
    print(allNums.sorted{ $0 < $1 })
}

generateRandNums {
    (-8..<2).random
}

generateRandNums {
    (0..<10).random
}

generateRandNums {
    (-10 ... -2).random
}

generateRandNums {
    rand(-5, 5)
}
generateRandNums {
    rand[0, 10]
}
```

### Sample result

[image]

Comment: This answer is off topic.  The question was how to generate a random number.  Not how to make a random number library.  Sheesh.