# iOS Swift Type Conversation Math causing app to Crash

Tags: ios, iphone, casting, type-conversion, swift

I have code that is meant to place a small UIView as a subview at a random X coordinate.

If I place the view at a fixed spot it works but when I calculate the random position my app crashes. Here is the code:

```
    @IBOutlet var gameView : UIView
    let DROP_SIZE = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)

    @IBAction func tap(sender : AnyObject) {
        self.drop()
    }

    func drop() {
        var frame = CGRect()
        frame.origin = CGPointZero
        frame.size = DROP_SIZE
        var x = Int(arc4random()) % Int(self.gameView.bounds.size.width) / Int(DROP_SIZE.width)
        frame.origin.x = CGFloat(x) * CGFloat(DROP_SIZE.width)
        var dropView: UIView = UIView(frame: frame)
        dropView.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        self.gameView.addSubview(dropView)

    }
```

whenever self.drop() is called my app crashes

If I comment out var x & frame.origin.x my app does not crash

So I know the issue is with these two lines of code:

```
var x = Int(arc4random()) % Int(self.gameView.bounds.size.width) / Int(DROP_SIZE.width)
frame.origin.x = CGFloat(x) * CGFloat(DROP_SIZE.width)
```

Something about the way these variables are casted is causing the app to crash because if I use a fixed x origin for example frame.origin.x = 100, then the app works as expected.

**UPDATE:**

because arc4random return UInt32 it will overflow when trying to convert it to an Int

I used this instead

```
var x = UInt32(arc4random()) % UInt32(self.gameView.bounds.size.width) / UInt32(DROP_SIZE.width)
frame.origin.x = CGFloat(x) * CGFloat(DROP_SIZE.width)
```

Comment: Is there any error message when crashing?

Comment: The error I receive highlights self.drop() with the text: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC+l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Interesting thing is sometimes it crashes right away, and sometimes it works for the first few taps then crashes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crash when casting the result of arc4random() to Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087518/crash-when-casting-the-result-of-arc4random-to-int)

Comment: arc4random returns a UInt32.  Half the time it will overflow an Int32 and crash on the mandatory bounds checking.  Seethe linked duplicate.

Comment: @David Nice find, missed that.

Comment: That exactly it thanks! It is now working if I convert all the numbers that are operating with the arc4random to UInt32

Comment: Better yet, follow the duplicate link and use arc4random_uniform.  It'll avid the problem *and* give you better results.

Comment: Ah got it working, I think the example has an extra ) in there but it works great thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because arc4random return UInt32 it will overflow when trying to convert it to an Int

I used this instead

```
var x = UInt32(arc4random()) % UInt32(self.gameView.bounds.size.width) / UInt32(DROP_SIZE.width)
frame.origin.x = CGFloat(x) * CGFloat(DROP_SIZE.width)
```

This issue is similar: [Crash when casting the result of arc4random() to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087518/crash-when-casting-the-result-of-arc4random-to-int)