# What is wrong with this "Do.. While" loop in Swift?

Tags: memory, swift, closures

I am trying to write [this](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial) in Swift (I am in step 54). In a `UICollectionViewLayout` class I have a function `setup` function

```
func setup() {
    var percentage  = 0.0
    for i in 0...RotationCount - 1 {

        var newPercentage = 0.0

        do {
            newPercentage = Double((arc4random() % 220) - 110) * 0.0001
            println(newPercentage)
        } while (fabs(percentage - newPercentage) < 0.006)

        percentage = newPercentage

        var angle = 2 * M_PI * (1 + percentage)
        var transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle), 0, 0, 1)
        rotations.append(transform)
    }
}
```

Here is how the `setup` function is described in the tutorial

> First we create a temporary mutable array that we add objects to. Then
>   we run through our loop, creating a rotation each time. We create a
>   random percentage between -1.1% and 1.1% and then use that to create a
>   tweaked CATransform3D. I geeked out a bit and added some logic to
>   ensure that the percentage of rotation we randomly generate is a least
>   0.6% different than the one generated beforehand. This ensures that photos in a stack don't have the misfortune of all being rotated the
>   same way. Once we have our transform, we add it to the temporary array
>   by wrapping it in an NSValue and then rinse and repeat. After all 32
>   rotations are added we set our private array property. Now we just
>   need to put it to use.

When I run the app, I get a run time error in the `while (fabs(percentage - newPercentage) < 0.006)` line.

[image]

the `setup` function is called in `prepareLayout()`

```
override func prepareLayout() {
    super.prepareLayout()
    setup()
    ...
}
```

Without the `do..while` loop, the app runs fine. So I am wondering, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to be more type safe

```
newPercentage = Double(Int((arc4random() % 220)) - 110) * 0.0001
```

Comment: Just beat me to it! Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24088457/919790

Answer (score 0):

This must be a Swift bug. That code should NOT crash at runtime.  It should either give a compiler error on the newPercentage = expression or it should correctly promote the types as C does.