# Swift Error: Type Underflow: Exec_Bad_Instruction

Tags: swift

Why do I get an error "EXEC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" for this:

```
let r = Double(arc4random_uniform(181) - 90)
```

while this works fine:

```
let r = Double(arc4random_uniform(181)) - 90
```

Using Swift in XCode 7.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crash when casting the result of arc4random() to Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087518/crash-when-casting-the-result-of-arc4random-to-int)

Comment: It work for me, however if I try multiple time I'm getting the same error what you got.

Comment: You will get the error whenever the `UInt32` returned by `arc4random_uniform` is less than 90

Comment: Oh I get it, because the result of arc4random_uniform is a UInt32 so I cannot substract more then the result itself because UInt32 can't be negative. I can however substract more than it's value after the conversion to Double because Double can be negative.

Comment: I have tried to catch this error with the address sanitizer in the Xcode but it didn't catch it as underflow exception during the runtime. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error, it's a feature of Swift. Swift will intentionally crash whenever you create an arithmetic overflow or underflow.

You will get an arithmetic underflow whenever arc4random_uniform(181) returns a value less than 90 and you try to subtract 90 from it. Since the result is not in the range of an unsigned 32 bit integer, Swift informs you about your mistake by crashing your program.

And it's not a "Double" error: You never get that far that the type "Double" is involved in this at all. It will crash just the same without the cast to Double.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the question title.

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of `arc4random_uniform` is of type `UInt32` I cannot become a negative value. So whenever the result of `arc4random_uniform` becomes less than `90` an error is thrown.

The value can become negative after the conversion to type `Double` because that type can hold a negative value. This is why the second line of code works.