# Swift 2 arc4random_uniform crash?

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a very simple execution, but it's crashing for some reason.  Any ideas why?

```
import UIKit  
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var myTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var resultsLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func pressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let diceRoll = String(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(6)))
    print(diceRoll)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

**Crash Log added**

> 2016-02-06 16:24:32.358 GuessingGame[6330:496415] * Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key TextField.' * First throw call stack: ( 0
>   CoreFoundation 0x000000010960ae65 exceptionPreprocess + 165 1
>   libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000010b34adeb objc_exception_throw + 48 2
>   CoreFoundation 0x000000010960aaa9 -[NSException raise] + 9 3
>   Foundation 0x00000001099d39bb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding)
>   setValue:forKey:] + 288 4 UIKit 0x0000000109fb6320 -[UIViewController
>   setValue:forKey:] + 88 5 UIKit 0x000000010a1e4f41
>   -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109 6 CoreFoundation 0x000000010954b4a0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224 7
>   UIKit 0x000000010a1e3924 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
>   8 UIKit 0x0000000109fbceea -[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381 9 UIKit 0x0000000109fbd816 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178 10 UIKit 0x0000000109fbdb74 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138 11 UIKit 0x0000000109fbe2e7 -[UIViewController view] + 27 12 UIKit
>   0x0000000109e94ab0 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] +
>   61 13 UIKit 0x0000000109e95199 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282 14
>   UIKit 0x0000000109ea6c2e -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42 15 UIKit
>   0x0000000109e1f663 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131 16 UIKit 0x0000000109e25cc6 -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760 17 UIKit 0x0000000109e22e7b -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
>   18 FrontBoardServices 0x000000010d1df754 -[FBSSerialQueue
>   _performNext] + 192 19 FrontBoardServices 0x000000010d1dfac2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45 20 CoreFoundation 0x0000000109536a31
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17 21 CoreFoundation 0x000000010952c95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556 22
>   CoreFoundation 0x000000010952be13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867 23
>   CoreFoundation 0x000000010952b828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488 24 UIKit
>   0x0000000109e227cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402 25 UIKit
>   0x0000000109e27610 UIApplicationMain + 171 26 GuessingGame
>   0x000000010942b4dd main + 109 27 libdyld.dylib 0x000000010be5392d
>   start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException (lldb)

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Where exactly are you getting a crash? Can you post the Console logs.

Comment: That code should work. Which specific line is crashing, and what is the exact error message?

Comment: I posted the full error message below. The error seems to be this:             class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate

Comment: minor improvements in formatting and grammar

Comment: Valid question -- related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087518/crash-when-casting-the-result-of-arc4random-to-int

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cause is that you renamed your IBOutlet from TextField to myTextField in your code (or added a new link but did not remove the old reference from the control in IB).