# Random Number Generation between user input variables in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, arc4random

How can I create a random number between two random numbers that come from user input variables in swift using arc4random().

Comment: There are so many answers on this site already for finding a random number between two numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one generate a random number in Apple's Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way that is easy to understand/implement is to:

1. Subtract the two numbers
2. Find a random number on this difference - 1
3. Add the random number back to the lower of the original two numbers to get a number in between the two.

for example:

```
let a: UInt32 = 1
let b: UInt32 = 8
let c = b - a - 1

let newRandomNumber = 1 + arc4random_uniform(c)
```

I'll let you work our what to do if b is the smaller number.