# How to generate a random number in Swift without repeating the previous random number?

Tags: swift

I'm pretty new to Swift and programming logic in general so bear with me

How can you generate a random number between 0 and 9 in Swift without repeating the last generated number? As in the same number won't come up twice in a row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one generate a random number in Apple's Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language)

Comment: No, without repetition

Comment: You can do that part. By putting a simple condition.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I don't know how to actually do that. That is why I am asking the question. As I said, I am very new to Swift

Comment: This can be done by only generating a single random number each time.  See my answer.

Comment: The answers on this page are profoundly bad!   The simple and correct answer is very well-known.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62514324/294884

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Store the previous generated number in a variable and compare the generated number to the previous number. If they match generate a new random number. Repeat the generation of new numbers until they don't match.

```
var previousNumber: UInt32? // used in randomNumber() 

func randomNumber() -> UInt32 {
    var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
    while previousNumber == randomNumber {
        randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
    }
    previousNumber = randomNumber
    return randomNumber
}
```

Comment: ... for which, in theory, any call to `randomNumber()` is not guaranteed to terminate for a given non-infinite amount of allowed iterations over the `while` loop (even if it, in practice, swiftly will :) ). For a deterministic solution (w.r.t. to program flow in the call to `randomNumber()`), [see vacawama:s clever answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27548748/4573247).

Comment: this answer is **totally wrong** and will crash.  it's an indeterminate algorithm - a very basic computer science mistake.

Comment: @Fattie: Can you elaborate? Why is it wrong? Under what conditions will this crash?

Comment: my bad, by crash I meant enter an infinite loop

Comment: `arc4random()` and also the new `Int.random(in:)` are well-tested pseudo-random number generators, they will not return the same number infinitely often. In the case of 10 numbers the probability of k repetitions is 1/10^k.

Comment: well yes but you can't program based on "should be ok" or "it's very unlikely anyone will ever try to use this with an array of length 1" or "we know that certain software packages are tested" or "this will never be used at scale where performance matters" etc!! .  no software can/should contain indeterminate loops. you just can't put a "naked while" in real software!   IF you TRULY have to put a naked while in a routine, you absolutely must add a safety limit (count to 100 or something and abandon if you reach 100).  all of this is incredibly moot, there is such a simple well-known solution

Comment: Even the Swift standard library uses such loops in their implementation of the Random functions: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Random.swift.

Answer (score 17):

my solution, i think its easy to understand

```
var nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

while nums.count > 0 {

    // random key from array
    let arrayKey = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(nums.count)))

    // your random number
    let randNum = nums[arrayKey] 

    // make sure the number isnt repeated
    nums.swapAt(arrayKey, nums.count-1)
    nums.removeLast()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Update for Swift 5**

Here is a nice trick to choose equally from the numbers that were not just previously chosen.

You have 10 numbers, but you only want to select from 9 numbers (0 through 9, but excluding the previous number).
If you reduce your range by 1, you can select from 9 random numbers and then just replace a repeated number with the previous top number of the range.  In this way, you only have to generate a single random number each time and you get uniformity.

This can be implemented as `Int.random(in:excluding:)` where you pass the value you want to `exclude`.

```
extension Int {
    static func random(in range: ClosedRange<Int>, excluding x: Int) -> Int {
        if range.contains(x) {
            let r = Int.random(in: Range(uncheckedBounds: (range.lowerBound, range.upperBound)))
            return r == x ? range.upperBound : r
        } else {
            return Int.random(in: range)
        }
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
// Generate 30 numbers in the range 1...3 without repeating the
// previous number  
var r = Int.random(in: 1...3)
for _ in 1...30 {
    r = Int.random(in: 1...3, excluding: r)
    print(r, terminator: " ")
}
print()
```

> 1 3 2 1 2 1 3 2 1 3 1 3 2 3 1 2 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 1 2 3 2 1 2 1 3 2 3 2 1 3 1 2 1 2

---

**Previous Answer:**

```
var previousNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)   // seed the previous number

func randomNumber() -> UInt32 {
    var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(9)  // generate 0...8
    if randomNumber == previousNumber {
        randomNumber = 9
    }
    previousNumber = randomNumber
    return randomNumber
}
```

Comment: @vacawama I see the trick here (uniformity for the 9 integers in the [0, 9] range where the previously chosen number has been excluded) now, thanks for explaining!

Comment: Peculiarly, leaving aside the array shuffling methods, this is the only one-random-number-at-a-time-method that is guaranteed to "terminate" among the answers to this thread ("terminating" not really being an interesting term in the very termination-deterministic solution here, but w.r.t. the brute-force-looping approach used e.g. in the accepted answer). So I leave this additional comment pointing out that I believe this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that this method works great for choosing a second number after a first has been chosen, but doesn't work as well when you want to choose n random and unique numbers from a pool of k numbers. A collection of some sort is needed at that point. I'd recommend looking at my solution to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029193/4273137

Comment: geez I'm sorry V but this answer is absolutely horrible.  it's an incredibly well-known, straightforward problem with a trivial, well-known solution!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62514324/294884

Comment: What exactly is “absolutely horrible”? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Fattie, I checked your link and the algorithm that you provide isn’t very different from mine. Both uniformly choose from n-1 choices to avoid the repeat. Logically what my algorithm does is replace the excluded value with the one in the nth position and then choose from n-1 values.

Comment: Vac regarding the upper solution. If I'm not mistaken, when there's a match you are choosing the "highest one".  So it's very unrandom.  Regarding the lower solution I believe it has the same problem.  Honestly the solution is dead simple, it's one of the most basic tricks of modulo arithmetic.

Comment: @Fattie, do you agree that if I first moved the highest value into the slot of the previous choice and then chose from those n-1 values that it would be random? That is exacly the same as sayiing, oh I chose the same value, so use the highest instead. The chance of picking the same value is 1/(n-1), so getting the highest value has the same chance as every other value.

Comment: @Fattie, my answer is just as good as yours in terms of picking a random value without repeat.  If you want to argue that doing modular arithmetic is faster than an "if", I'll give you that.  But that hardly makes my answer horrible.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is with repeat/while:

```
let current = ...
var next: Int

repeat {
    next = Int(arc4random_uniform(9))
} while current == next

// Use `next`
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the values you want into an array, generate a random number using arc4random_uniform(SIZEOFARRAY) and pull the index of the random value from the array, and then repeat this process until the array is empty.