# Sprite Kit Random Value never twice

Tags: ios, swift, random, sprite-kit

I want to get a random value between 5 defined points, without getting the same result twice.

Here is a good explanation of how to avoid the same result twice:
[How to generate a random number in Swift without repeating the previous random number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541145/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-swift-without-repeating-the-previous-random-n)

However, in my Code it doesn't work as it still is completely random, and I can't see why.

```
 func addWall(){

    let positions = [
        CGPoint(x: -120,y: -70),
        CGPoint(x: -50,y: -70),
        CGPoint(x: 10,y: -70),
        CGPoint(x: 70,y: -70),
        CGPoint(x: 120, y: -70),
    ]

    var previousPosition : Int?

    func randomPosition() -> Int {
        var randomPosition = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(positions.count)))
        while previousPosition == randomPosition {
            randomPosition = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(positions.count)))
        }
        previousPosition = randomPosition
        return randomPosition
    }

    Wall.position = positions[randomPosition()]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property

```
var previousPosition : Int?
```

is *local* to the `addWall()` method, and therefore initialized to `nil`
each time the method is called. If you make it a property of the
surrounding class instead:

```
class YourClass {

    var previousPosition : Int?

    func addWall() { ... }

    // ...
}
```

then it is initialized to `nil` only when an instance of the class
is created.