# How to make array of 30 different unique random numbers?

Tags: arrays, swift, random

I want to use `arc4random` to generate array of 30 different numbers, so that there is no repeating in it. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to make for loop and to use array.contains(n) but it either doesn’t fill all 30 numbers or it repeats some of them. I am stucked.

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773593/generate-array-of-unique-random-numbers-within-inclusive-range

Answer (score 2):

It may be a pretty heavy action but you can do like that:

```
   var randomNumbers: [Int] = []
   while randomNumbers.count != 30{

       let number = Int(arc4random_uniform(1000) + 1)
       if randomNumbers.contains(number) {
          print("Already Exits")
       }else{
          randomNumbers.append(number)
       }
   }
```

replace "1000" for a range of number that you need. That function generated 30 different number between 0...1000

Comment: Thank you, your'e a life saver!

Comment: Can you make it the right answer? @VladimirSukanica

Answer (score 2):

## Update:

Thanks to [@Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan) for his elegant thought (commented on [Gereon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51619157/5501940)):

> anyway, depending on the difference between limit and the number of
>   generated elements this can have a terrible performance. The problem
>   is the case when limit is close to the number of generated elements.
>   Then it would be much better to take `1..<limit` and shuffle it.

Which means that there is no even need to generate random `Int`. The simplest way I could think of is to do it as (**Swift 4.2**):

```
let randoms = Array(0..<30).shuffled()
```

therefore `randoms` is an array of `Int`s, contains 30 unique values from 0 to 29.

**Less Than Swift 4.2:**

However, if you are not using Swift 4.2, I would recommend to check [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/5501940) for getting shuffled collection.

---

## Ignored Solution:

You could achieve it like this:

```
var uniques = Set<UInt32>()

func generateUniqueUInt32() -> UInt32 {
    let random = arc4random_uniform(31)

    if !uniques.contains(random) {
        uniques.insert(random)
        return random
    } else {
        return generateUniqueUInt32()
    }
}


let randomArray = Array(0..<30).map { _ in Int(generateUniqueUInt32()) }
```

Therefore `randomArray` is an array of `Int`s, contains 30 unique values from 0 to 29.

**Swift 4.2:**

You should replace:

```
let random = arc4random_uniform(31)
```

with:

```
let random = Int.random(in: 1..<30)
```

which means that `generateUniqueUInt32` should return -directly- `Int` (and renamed to `generateUniqueInt`):

```
func generateUniqueInt() -> Int {
    let random = Int.random(in: 1..<30)

    if !uniques.contains(random) {
        uniques.insert(random)
        return random
    } else {
        return generateUniqueInt()
    }
}

let randomArray = Array(0..<30).map { _ in generateUniqueInt() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set` to store the generated numbers so far

```
func thirtyUniqueRandomNumbers(_ limit: Int) -> [Int] {
    var randoms = Set<Int>()
    repeat {
        let rnd = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(limit)))
        if !randoms.contains(rnd) {
            randoms.insert(rnd)
        }
    } while randoms.count < 30
    return randoms.map { $0 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe we could start using Swift 4.2, e.g. `Int.random(in: 0 ... 10)`?

Comment: Absolutely, once we have a non-beta version.

Comment: anyway, depending on the difference between `limit` and the number of generated elements this can have a terrible performance. The problem is the case when `limit` is close to the number of generated elements.  Then it would be much better to take `1..<limit` and shuffle it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. Start a `while` loop. Within this loop generate a random number (between 0 and 1000). And then append the number into your array if the array doesn't contains the number.

```
func generateArrayOfRandomNumbers() -> [Int] {
    var array: [Int] = []
    while array.count < 30 {
        let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0...1000)
        guard !array.contains(randomInt) else { continue }
        array.append(randomInt)
    }
    return array
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.