# How to load specific data items from a JSON file using SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I am pretty new to coding so apologies if this should be straightforward for me.

I am using SwiftUI on Xcode, and am using JSON for my data.

I have the JSON file which contains just 7 items: 1 Int and 6 Strings (1 of those an array).
I have a model file that maps the data items in JSON to SwiftUI variables.
I have a data loader that reads the JSON file and does the correct error checking etc.
I have a view that can show the data read from the JSON file.

I need to be able to read the data set for a specific record in the data.  When I run my code currently I get the 1st item returned successfully but would now need to amend the code to be able to pull whichever record I require from the dataset.

```
let questions: [Question] = Bundle.main.decode("questions.json")
```

then in the body, I use this format to output any data item to the screen (question is one of the variable names defined in the model)

```
        Text(question.question)
```

but of course, this only ever returns the first item in the JSON file.  How do I read a specific data item please based on one of the items in the JSON file?
...

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "qn": "1",
    "level": "1",
    "sylabusItem": "1A2",
    "question": "Dummy question 2",
    "answers": ["Dummy answer 1", "Pretend answer 2", "Pretend answer 3", "Pretend answer 4"],
    "correct": "2",
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "qn": "1",
    "level": "1",
    "sylabusItem": "1A2",
    "question": "Dummy question 3",
    "answers": ["Dummy answer 1", "Another answer 2", "Another answer 3", "Another answer 4"],
    "correct": "4",
}
```

Model file

...

```
        struct Question: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
            var id: Int
            var qn: String
            var level: String
            var sylabusItem: String
            var question: String
            var answers: [String]
            var correct: String


            static let allQuestions: [Question] = Bundle.main.decode("questions.json")
            static let example = allQuestions[0]
        }
```

Hope I have provided enough info.  Thanks all.

Comment: And what do you mean with “ read a specific data item”? Specific as in searching for a question or a specific index or...? Or do you want to iterate over the array?

Comment: The data is a list of questions, with multi choice answers and some other data related to the question etc.  I would like to be able to read the 'nth' question set of data out of the JSON file.  I also want to be able to iterate over parts of the array.  The data will comprise many questions, say 100 in total, with the test comprising 10 questions.  Qn 1 will be 1 question selected randomly from the 1st 10, question 2 will again be 1 question selected by the system randomly from 11-20, 3rd question again 1 selected randomly from 21-30 etc.

Comment: That's a lot of things you want to do but to get you started look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773593/generate-array-of-unique-random-numbers-within-inclusive-range) for some ideas on how to generate a unique random number (index) for getting your questions.

Comment: I am able to generate random numbers @JoakimDanielson, it's knowing how to extract specific data out of a JSON file is what I am after.

Comment: You shouldn't. You have your array of questions and that is what you should use, `let questions: [Question] = Bundle.main.decode("questions.json")`

Comment: Yep, that's what I am not knowing how to do.  Say I want to get item 24 in the data set.  How do I do that @JoakimDanielson.  I will need to generate a random number each time I wish to extract a random question in the sections from 11-20 or 21-30 etc.

Comment: `let question = questions[23]`. To learn more about arrays check out [this chapter](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107) in the Swift Programming Language book

Comment: I'm Stil lunsure though @JoakimDanielson how to simply point to any item in the JSON file.  All I ca do is return the first item.