# How to generate a random number that is not the same as the last

Tags: swift, random

Before I say anything, please note that this is not a duplicate of:
**

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541145/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-swift-without-repeating-the-previous-random-n/27541537#27541537)

Because I have tried using all the answers from that question, but they all come up as errors because of the UINT32.

So, how can I generate a random number using `arc4random` but not making it the same number as last time?

Comment: check this  link might be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132399/how-does-one-make-random-number-between-range-for-arc4random-uniform

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a few Minutes to review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Could you show what you have tried already and what your specific problems are? This makes it very easy for people to help you!

Comment: Have a variable save the last random number. Then do a `while (newRandomNumber == oldRandomNumber) { newRandomNumber = generateRandomNumber(); }`

Comment: Why does the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27541269/1187415 not work for you? What code did you try and what errors exactly did you get? *"as errors because of the UINT32"* is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution without using UINT32

```
var previousNumber: Int? // used in randomNumber()

func randomNumber() -> Int {
    var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    while previousNumber == randomNumber {
        randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    }
    previousNumber = randomNumber
    return randomNumber
}
```