# If statements to find duplicate values?

Tags: arrays, swift

Ok lets say I have a list which generates values randomly and sometimes it generates the same value twice.

For example generated int value:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Then I have a method called duplicateTracker() and its job is to find duplicates within the list.

I have an idea that it should be done using if else statements. So if it detects duplicate numbers its then true, else false.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can use `if` statement to find if a *small, fixed* number of items contains duplicates. When the number of items is not fixed at compile time, or when it is large (three or four being a practical maximum) you need to use a loop and a container of what you've seen so far, or a pair of nested loops.

Comment: `if Set(numbers).count < numbers.count { print("duplicates exist") }`

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to add the elements to a set one by one, and check if it's already in the set. If it is, it's a duplicate, else it's new.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541145/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-swift-without-repeating-the-previous-random-n

func randomNumber() -> UInt32 {
    var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
    while previousNumber == randomNumber {
        randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
    }
    previousNumber = randomNumber
    return randomNumber
}

Comment: Do you need to know which numbers have duplicates or only if there are duplicates?

Comment: @JPetric yes. THe duplicateTracker method should only detect dupliates of numbers (for example) 1, 10 and 20. It should ignore duplicates of other numbers

Answer (score 1):

This makes use of Foundation methods but given your use case, you might want to consider making us of an [`NSCountedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscountedset) to keep track of your generated numbers. E.g.

```
let numbersGenerator = AnyIterator { return 1 + arc4random_uniform(10) }
var numbersBag = NSCountedSet()

for num in (0...15).flatMap({ _ in numbersGenerator.next()}) {
    print(num, terminator: " ")
    numbersBag.add(num)
} /* 1 3 2 2 10 1 10 7 10 6 8 3 8 10 7 4 */
print()

numbersBag.forEach { print($0, numbersBag.count(for: $0)) }
/* 1 2
   2 2
   3 2
   4 1
   6 1
   7 2
   8 2
   10 4 */
```

Since `NSCountedSet` conforms to `Sequence`, you can easily extract any "duplicate diagnostics" that you wish using e.g. `filter`:

```
print("Numbers with duplicates: ", numbersBag.filter { numbersBag.count(for: $0) > 1 })
// Numbers with duplicates: [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this function:

```
func checkForDups(_ arr1:[Int], _ arr2:[Int]) -> Bool {
    let arrChecked = Set(arr1).subtracting(Set(arr2))
    if Set(arr1).count != arrChecked.count {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Here's code that works:

```
let arr1:[Int] = [1,1,2,3,4,5]
let arr2:[Int] = [1,10,20]
let arr3:[Int] = [10,20,30]
print(checkForDups(arr1, arr2))  // prints true
print(checkForDups(arr1, arr3))  // prints false
```