# Six random numbers, but repeating? How not repeat? Swift

Tags: swift, random, numbers

I have this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func geraNumeros(_ sender: Any) {
        var numeroAleatorio:[Int] = []

        for _ in 1...6 {
            numeroAleatorio.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(60)+1))
        }

        numeroAleatorio.sort()

        labelNumeros.text = "\(numeroAleatorio[0]) - \(numeroAleatorio[1]) - \(numeroAleatorio[2]) - \(numeroAleatorio[3]) - \(numeroAleatorio[4]) - \(numeroAleatorio[5]) "

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var labelNumeros: UILabel!
}
```

But sometimes numbers repeating, like:

10 - 18 - 12 - 10 - 30 - 60

Like 10-10, so what to do?

Comment: Sometimes randomly generated numbers repeat. Consider when you throw a dice; you're not guaranteed a different number each time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541145/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-swift-without-repeating-the-previous-random-n.

Comment: @FelipeRibeiro https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zu5a6r0zdde99o/Sena%20Combination%20Generator.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 0):

Before appending the value to your array, check if it is already present in your array using the `.contains()` function. If it exists, continue the loop until we have the 6 elements we need.

For this to work you must change your loop to keep looping until 6 valid elements are found.

Something like

```
while numeroAleatorio.count < 6
```