# How to print all numbers from this dictionary in a random order without repeating them

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, arc4random

The code crashes after 3 tries.
How do I manage to print all 10 values without repeating them?

```
var windCard = [1:11,  2:12,  3:21,  4:22,  5:31,  6:32,  7:41,  8:42, 9:51, 10:52 ]

var die = 0
die = Int(arc4random())%windCard.count

print("The wind blow the mosquitoes \(windCard[Int(die)]!)")
windCard.removeValue(forKey: die)
```

Comment: Hint: `die` will be a value from `0` to `9`.

Comment: but every time I remove the value the length of the dictionary gets shorter

Comment: OK, then the value of `die` will be `0` to `windCard.count - 1`. So initially `9` and decreasing each time. The `0` should make you go "Oh!".

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541145/how-to-generate-a-random-number-in-swift-without-repeating-the-previous-random-n/27541537

Comment: I still dont understand, the code still only works 3 time before crashing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Int(arc4random())%windCard.count` generates keys in the range `0` to `windCard.count-1`, while your keys start from 1 and after you remove the first element, the keys won't even be contiguous. So for instance if you remove a key from the middle of your `Dictionary` (let's say key `5`), `windCard` will have 9 elements and hence `die` will be in the range `0-8`, but your `Dictionary` will be missing a key, so your code will crash on `windCard[key]!` if `die` is `5`.

You can achieve your goal by using `arc4random_uniform`, which accepts an `upperBound` input argument and using the generated random number to subscript the `keys` of your `windCard` `Dictionary`, which will guaranteed to be contiguous.

```
while windCard.count > 0 {
    let die = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(windCard.keys.count)))
    let key = Array(windCard.keys)[die]
    print("The wind blow the mosquitoes \(windCard[key]!)")
    windCard.removeValue(forKey: key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be to store the random number you get in every loop in a temp file or database, then compare the new values, if they match, generate a new random value, and then compare again against file or database, that way even if they match you assure you get a genuine value each time. Hope this "algorithm" helps you.

Comment: Why would you waste time and resources for storing temporary values in a file/database? Simply store them in a data structure in memory.