# Generate random number in range with SecRandomCopyBytes

Tags: java, ios, swift, secure-random

I'm using [`SecRandomCopyBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecRandomCopyBytes) for generate a secure random number.

Is there a way to specify a "range"?

I need to obtain the same behaviour of this `Java` piece of code:

```
SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
char x = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
```

Any tips will appreciate!

**UPDATE**

Seeing that I made a silly question I feel compelled to share the solution, made extending Int type:

```
public extension Int {
  /**
  Create a random num Int in range
  :param: lower number Int
  :param: upper number Int
  :return: random number Int
  */
  public static func random(#min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
     return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1))) + min
  }

  /**
  Create a secure random num Int in range
  :param: lower number Int
  :param: upper number Int
  :return: random number Int
  */
  public static func secureRandom(#min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    if max == 0 {
        NSException(name: "secureRandom", reason: "max number must be > 0", userInfo: nil).raise()
    }
    var randomBytes = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(8)
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 8, randomBytes)
    let randomNumber = unsafeBitCast(randomBytes, UInt.self)
    return Int(randomNumber) % max + min
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't return random number between min..max but in the range min..(min+max) I would rather suggest using Swift's 4.2 implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39768472/1245231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always specify a range by applying modulo and addition, check this pseudocode:

```
// random number in the range 1985-2014 
r = rand() % 30 + 1985
```

Comment: Oh.. I just realized I made the stupidest question in the story!

Comment: haha no worries :D sometimes the instinct let's you post a question before thinking it through ;)

Comment: This also happens after hours of code-porting! Kill me!

Comment: This solution will result in a biased random number generator unless your max argument happens to be divisible by UInt8.max. This problem is commonly referred to as modulo bias. See this post for a great explanation, and a more secure solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984975

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Swift 4.2** allows to generate random numbers using `Int` class:

```
let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 26)
```

The random source should be cryptographically secure [SystemRandomNumberGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/systemrandomnumbergenerator)

See also:

- [Generating random numbers in Swift](https://theswiftdev.com/2018/08/07/generating-random-numbers-in-swift/)
- [How to generate random numbers in Swift 4.2 and later](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/102/how-to-generate-random-numbers-in-swift)

**Old answer:**
iOS 9 introduced GameplayKit which provides `SecureRandom.nextInt()` Java equivalent.

To use it in **Swift 3**:

```
import GameplayKit

// get random Int
let randomInt = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: 26)
```

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31215189/1245231

Comment: Not crypto safe according to: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkrandom

Comment: @Ivan Swift 4.2 should use crypto secure random source. Please see the edited answer.