# Display random image with ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I finally was able to pull an array of images from **Parse.com** after fiddling with tutorials.

From that array I want to throw it on an image view via next random image with a swipe gesture:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"cats")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        for object in objects! {
            // Update - replaced as with as!
            self.imageFiles.append(object as! PFObject)
            println(self.imageFiles)
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The `println(self.imageFiles)` actually shows the array of files which is great, what I'm having issues with is using the random generator.

Still new to syntax, I was trying to do like `imageview.image = imageFiles[0]` or something like that to just display one of the images in the array. Not really sure the syntax though.

I'm guessing once I get that it would be `imageview.image = imageFiles[RandomNumber]` or the equivalent.

for the swipe part I think I got that under control

**Edit**

ok I have:

```
let randomNumber = imageFiles[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageFiles.count)))]
println(randomNumber)
```

and the println gives me a random image file from the array.

How do I put that into the image view?

**EDIT**
just tried:

```
for randomNumber in imageFiles {
    self.ImageView.image = randomNumber
}
```

and got:

cannot assign a value type pfobject to a value type of uiimage

```
self.ImageView.image = UIImage(data: randomNumber)
```

also gives me an error can't have data: `PFObject`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language for generating a random integer in Swift. Then just use that with your imageFiles array as you described.

Comment: Could you provide a print screen of your "cats" database in Parse? This will help to determine how you will actually retrieve the image itself, because right now you are just retrieving data about a "cat" object, thus a reference to the image

Comment: Its just a list of 10 images. I have retreaved them Im just not sure how to display an element of the array. Also I know the method for random that is not the issue. I am not sure how to put it into an image view.