# How to convert PFObject array in image view?

Tags: xcode, swift, random, parse-platform, uiimageview

Sorry guys I want to try this again just reword it so its understandable.

ImageFiles is an array of PFObjects, about 10 images

```
let randomNumber = imageFiles[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageFiles.count)))]

    println(randomNumber)
```

and the println gives me a random image file from the array.

How do I put that into the image view? Meaning i want a random element of the array to be viewable in the uiimage view.

```
let image = UIImage(data: randomNumber as AnyObject as! NSData)
```

closest I've got... no syntax error only runtime

Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' (0x105639070) to 'NSData' (0x106c97a48).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An actual image stored in Parse is not of the format `PFObject`, it is of the type `PFFile`. Normally a reference to a `PFFile` is stored within a `PFObject`.

I can imagine your code/pseudocode will end up looking like the following:

```
let myRandomImageMetaData = imageFiles[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageFiles.count)))]
let imageFileReference: PFFile = myRandomImageMetaData["imgLink"]
```

The actual code will depend on your database structure which I've already asked you for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468004/display-random-image-with-imageview#comment50913528_31468004), but you never provided.

---

Now that you have the file reference, then you actually have to download the image data itself. You can do it like so:

```
imageFileReference.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        if let imageData = imageData {
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about storing and retrieving images stored as `PFFile` in Parse here:

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files-images

---

Now, your next problem is that you have not known all of this while uploading the images in the first place. So there is a high risk that you've uploaded the images to Parse badly in the first place and that the images doesn't exist there at all.

Comment: ok man. Sorry I was just digging myself a hole, lets try and do this right. editing with a screen. one question I am not 100% sure on: what exactly is "imgLink"? is it just a naming convention? I actually ended up deleting the class and remaking it just to make sure it was working or whatever. I don't need any form of adding images in app, just need to pull it. so I just clicked on add file from the website.

Comment: `imgLink` is the name of the property. In your case, based on the print screen, it should be named `image`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764618/swift-image-retrieving-from-parse-sdk-getting-crashed more or less helped me. let randmoNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(objects!.count))) that prints out a random number. so that is a start. all I want to do now is go like (following that example using thumbNail. I want like thumbNail[randomNumber]. says "PFFile does not have a member named 'subscript'"

Comment: Okay I'm over the random part. just want to swipe through the array.

Comment: Im going to try this UIScroll view and see if that works.

Comment: You should just focus on the simplest scenario first before thinking about all that swiping stuff, which is to just download 1 image and display it in an imageview. Once you have this working, then you can start focusing on displaying a random image from the array

Comment: Ive got the single image, or rather its loading I have the whole array loaded and its just choosing an image to display

Comment: cat photo uploaded every time I run the app it shows a random image, which i guess its based on the timing of when it initializes

Comment: Since you have successfully managed to download and display a random image from your array, then it fulfils your original question: `How to convert PFObject array in image view?`. Instead you'll need to create a new question related to the swiping features. Feel free to post a link to that question here so I can follow up on it :)