# Generic Random Function in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, random, arc4random

I have researched and looked into many different random function, but the downside to them is that they only work for one data type. I want a way to have one function work for a Double, Floats, Int, CGFloat, etc. I know I could just convert it to different data types, but I would like to know if there is a way to have it done using generics. Does someone know a way to make a generic random function using swift. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25129039/1187415.

Comment: Yes, this is good, though I would like it to be able to be for more than just Ints. Refer above to the question, I edited it slightly.

Answer (score 4):

In theory you could port code such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686353/c-random-float-number-generation) (which is *not* necessarily a great solution, depending on your needs, since `UInt32.max` is relatively small)

```
extension FloatingPointType {
    static func rand() -> Self {
        let num = Self(arc4random())
        let denom = Self(UInt32.max)
        // this line won’t compile:
        return num / denom
    }
}

// then you could do
let d = Double.rand()
let f = Float.rand()
let c = CGFloat.rand()
```

Except… `FloatingPointType` doesn’t conform to a protocol that guarantees operators like `/`, `+` etc (unlike `IntegerType` which conforms to `_IntegerArithmeticType`).

You could do this manually though:

```
protocol FloatingPointArithmeticType: FloatingPointType {
    func /(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    // etc
}

extension Double: FloatingPointArithmeticType { }
extension Float: FloatingPointArithmeticType { }
extension CGFloat: FloatingPointArithmeticType { }

extension FloatingPointArithmeticType {
    static func rand() -> Self {
        // same as before
    }
}

// so these now work
let d = Double.rand()  // etc
```

but this probably isn’t quite as out-of-the-box as you were hoping (and no doubt contains some subtle invalid assumption about floating-point numbers on my part).

As for something that works across both integers *and* floats, the Swift team have mentioned on their mail groups before that the lack of protocols spanning both types is a conscious decision since it’s rarely correct to write the same code for both, and that’s certainly the case for generating random numbers, which need two very different approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Before you get too far into this, think about what you want the behavior of a type-agnostic random function to be, and whether that's something that you want. It sounds like you're proposing something like this:

```
// signature only
func random<T>() -> T

// example call sites, with specialization by inference from declared result type
let randInt: Int = random()
let randFloat: Float = random()
let randDouble: Double = random()
let randInt64: Int = random()
```

(Note this syntax is sort of fake: without a parameter of type `T`, the implementation of `random<T>()` can't determine which type to return.)

What do you expect the possible values in each of these to be? Is `randInt` always a value between zero and `Int.max`? (Or maybe between zero and `UInt32.max`?) Is `randFloat` always between 0.0 and 1.0? Should `randDouble` actually have a larger count of possible values than `randFloat` (per the increased resolution between 0.0 and 1.0 of the `Double` type)? How do you account for the fact that `Int` is actually `Int32` on 32-bit systems and `Int64` on 64-bit hardware?

Are you sure it makes sense to have two (or more) calls that look identical but return values in different ranges?

---

Second, do you really want "arbitrarily random" random number generation everywhere in your app/game? Most use of RNGs is in game design, where typically there are a couple of important things you want in your RNG before you get your product past the prototyping stage:

- **Independence**: I've seen games where you could learn to predict the next "random" enemy encounter based on recent "random" NPC chitchat/emotes. If you're using random elements in multiple gameplay systems, you don't want
- **Determinism**: If you want to be able to reproduce a sequence of game events — either for testing/debugging or for consistent results between clients in a networked game — you don't want to be using a random function where you can't control that sequence. `arc4random` doesn't let you control the initial seed, and you have no control over the sequence because you don't know what other code in your process (library code, or just other code of your own that you forgot about) is also pulling numbers from the generator.

(If you're not making a game... much of this still applies, though it may be less important. You still don't want to be re-running your test case until the heat death of the universe trying to randomly find the same bug that one of your users reported.)

---

In iOS 9 / OS X 10.11 / tvOS, GameplayKit provides a suite of randomization tools to address these issues.

```
let randA = GKARC4RandomSource()
let someNumbers = (0..<1000).map { _ in randA.nextInt() }
let randB = GKARC4RandomSource()
let someMoreNumbers = (0..<1000).map { _ in randB.nextInt() }
let randC = GKARC4RandomSource(seed: randA.seed)
let evenMoreNumbers = (0..<1000).map { _ in randC.nextInt() }
```

Here, `someMoreNumbers` is *always* nondeterministic, no matter what happens in the generation of `someNumbers` or what other randomization activity happens on the system. And `evenMoreNumbers` is the exact same sequence of numbers as `someNumbers`.

---

Okay, so the GameplayKit syntax isn't quite what you want? Well, some of that is a natural consequence of having to manage RNGs as objects so that you can keep them independent and deterministic. But if you really want to have a super-simple `random()` call that you can slot in wherever needed, regardless of return type, *and* be independent and deterministic...

Here's one possible recipe for that. It implements `random()` as a static function on a type extension, so that you can use type-inference shorthand to write it; e.g.:

```
// func somethingThatTakesAnInt(a: Int, andAFloat Float: b)
somethingThatTakesAnInt(.random(), andAFloat: random())
```

The first parameter automatically calls `Int.random()` and the second calls `Float.random()`. (This is the same mechanism that lets you use shorthand for referring to enum cases, or `.max` instead of `Int.max`, etc.)

And it makes the type extensions `private`, with the idea that different source files will want independent RNGs.

```
// EnemyAI.swift
private extension Int {
    static func random() -> Int {
        return EnemyAI.die.nextInt()
    }
}

class EnemyAI: NSObject {
    static let die = GKARC4RandomSource()
    // ...
}
```

```
// ProceduralWorld.swift
private extension Int {
    static func random() -> Int {
        return ProceduralWorld.die.nextInt()
    }
}

class ProceduralWorld: NSObject {
    static let die = GKARC4RandomSource()
    // ... 
}
```

Repeat with extensions for more types as desired.

If you add some breakpoints or logging to the different `random()` functions you'll see that the two implementations of `Int.random()` are specific to the file they're in.

Anyway, that's a lot of boilerplate, but perhaps it's good food for thought...

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd probably write individual implementations for each thing you wanted. There just aren't that many, and it's a lot safer and more flexible. But… sure, you can do this. Just create a random bit pattern and say "that's a number."

```
func randomValueOfType<T>(type: T.Type) -> T {
    let size = sizeof(type)
    let bits = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(1)
    arc4random_buf(bits, size)
    return bits.memory
}
```

(This is technically "that's a something" but if you pass it something other than number-like types, you'll probably crash because most random bit patterns aren't a legal object.)

I believe every possible bit pattern will generate a legal IEEE 754 number, but "legal" may be more complex than you're thinking. A "totally random" float would rightly include NaN (not-a-number) which will show up reasonably often in your results.

There are some other special cases like the infinities and negative zero, but in practice those should never occur. Any single bit pattern showing up in a random choice of 32-bits is effectively zero. There are lots of NaN bit patterns, so it shows up a lot.

And that's the problem with this whole approach. If your random generator can accept that NaN shows up, then it's probably testing real floating point. But if you're testing real floating point, you really want to be checking the edge cases like infinity and negative zero. But if you don't want to include NaN, then you don't really mean "a random `Float`" you mean "a random Real number that can be expressed as a `Float`." There's no type for that, so you would need to write specific logic to handle it, and if you're doing that, you might as well write a specialized random generator for each type.

But this function is probably still a useful foundation for building that. You could just generate values until one is a legal number (NaN doesn't show up *that* often, so you'll almost certainly get it in less than 2 tries).

This kind of emphasizes the point Airspeed Velocity made about why there's no generic "number" protocol. You usually can't just treat floating point numbers like integers. They just work differently, and you very often need to think about that fact.