# Random Number Generator for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, random

I'm building an app for both Android and iOS. In the app, I need to generate psuedorandom numbers that match in both the iOS version and the Android version. I'be seen many implementations of custom random number generators but some are in C++ or PHP... I only know Java and Swift. Can someone help me and point me to a random generator that would work on both iOS and Android or can someone tell em the steps on how to create my own random number generator?

Edit: By 'match' I meant that I need to be able to seed it so that it will produce the same output every single time.

Comment: what are the difficulties to implement that on each platform its way? On android it's `new Random().nextInt()`

Comment: Here is the link which can be of help for you. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language)

Comment: What do you mean by "match"?

Comment: Why not just do something dead simple like XORShift, which is one line of code in any language?

Answer (score 0):

```
randomValue = arc4random() % 255;
```

Generate Randome Value between 0 to 255 On iOS

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting "match" to mean you'd like the iOS and Android implementations to yield the same sequence of values if seeded identically.  You can do this using a standard implementation of [Mersenne Twister, mt19937](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html).  Apple has an implementation available in Swift via GameplayKit.  You can confirm its behavior and replicability in a Playground:

```
import GameplayKit

let source = GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource(seed: 123)
source.nextUniform()               // => 0.3132002
source.nextUniform()               // => 0.5559791
source.nextIntWithUpperBound(20)   // => 13

let source2 = GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource(seed: 123)
source2.nextUniform()              // => 0.3132002
source2.nextUniform()              // => 0.5559791
source2.nextIntWithUpperBound(20)  // => 13
```

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource_Class/),

> ...if you initialize a GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource instance and a
>   compatible implementation using the same seed value, both generate the
>   same sequence of numbers.

I'm reading that to say it should produce a "match" with a C++ or Java reference implementation, source for which can be downloaded from the mt19937 site linked above.

---

ADDENDUM

It looks like the GameplayKit implementation gives reproducible results, but the output is not consistent with the reference implementation from Hiroshima. [Here's a port](https://github.com/PaulSanchez/mt19937-swift.git) to Swift that I did a couple of years ago of the standard C implementation for mt19937.  This produces identical outcomes as the C reference implementation when seeded identically.  So does the Java port available at the link provided earlier, so this should give you a solution which is consistent across platforms.

Comment: It worked in Swift but I still haven't found a code that works the same with Java.