# Cant seem to get past this line of code

Tags: ios, swift

What am I doing wrong? It won't let me use random.

```
PickRandom()

func PickRandom() {
    let RandomNumber = random() % QuizObject.count // error here
    Btn1.setTitle(QuizObject[RandomNumber].Answers[0])
    Btn2.setTitle(QuizObject[RandomNumber].Answers[1])
    Btn3.setTitle(QuizObject[RandomNumber].Answers[2])
    Btn4.setTitle(QuizObject[RandomNumber].Answers[3])
    QuestionLabel.setText(QuizObject[RandomNumber].Question)
    RealAnswer = QuizObject[RandomNumber].Answer
}

func RightWrong(){
    if (NumberPicked == RealAnswer) {
        PickRandom()
        QuestionLabel.setTextColor(UIColor.white)
    } else {
        QuestionLabel.setTextColor(UIColor.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Next time, please format your code. 2) Update your question with the error message.

Comment: And you may wish to review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language

Answer (score 0):

Write  `import Darwin` and use `arc4random()` instead of `random()`... This will resolve your error

Comment: Thank you guys. have a nice day