# Seeded random numbers with upper bound in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, srand, random-seed

Is there any way to seed the random number generator and also specify an upper bound in Swift 3?

Comment: If you're seeding the random number generator, aren't you using the wrong random number generator? `arc4random_uniform` doesn't need seeding.

Comment: Yes but the project I am working on requires the random number generator to be seeded. (I am attempting the Perlin Noise Algorithm in Swift 3)

Comment: [How does one generate a random number in Apple's Swift language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language)

Comment: Well, a common way is to use `arc4random_uniform("upper bound")`. This solves the upper bound problem but this is an unseeded random number generator. There also exists `srand48("seed")`, this plants the seed and then you can use `drand48()` to produce a random number between 0.0 and 1.0, this solves the seeding problem but does not allow you to produce a number out of the range of 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Never used drand48() but can't you just multiply its 0.0 to 1.0 output by your upper bound?

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient random number generators in Swift reside in GameKit. This generates random integers between -10 and 10 (inclusive):

```
import GameKit
let source = GKARC4RandomSource(seed: Data(bytes: [42]))
let random = GKRandomDistribution(randomSource: source, lowestValue: -10, highestValue: 10)

for _ in 0..<10 {
    print(random.nextInt())
}
```