# Xcode: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: xcode, arguments, cgsize

I'm currently working on an App where Meteors should spawn randomly as enemies. I have this code:

```
let randomXStart = random(min: CGSize, max: CGSize)
let randomXEnd = random(min: CGSize, max: CGSize)
```

Which returns:

```
Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
```

I'm currently using xcode 9.3.1.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are writing Swift code. There is no `random()` method in Swift.
If you want to create random numbers, you can reference the following.

[How does one generate a random number in Apple's Swift language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language)