# UIImageView UIImage String Value Swift 4

Tags: swift, string, image, uiimageview

I'm trying to get the String value from a `UIImageView`'s `UIImage` when `touchesBegan`.

here is the entire viewcontroller code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var imageOne: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageTwo: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var myText: UILabel!

    let imagesArray = ["banaan", "auto", "kip", "boom" ]

    var questionArray: [String] = []

    var touchArray: [CGPoint] = []

    var itemOne: Int!
    var itemTwo: Int!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupQuestions()
        setupImages()
    }

    //MARK: Randomizing The Lable Question
    fileprivate func setupQuestions() {
        let firstRandomizer = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imagesArray.count))
        let secondRandomizer = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imagesArray.count))
        itemOne = Int(firstRandomizer)
        itemTwo = Int(secondRandomizer)

        if itemOne == itemTwo && itemTwo != 0 {
            itemTwo -= 1
        } else if itemOne == itemTwo && itemTwo == 0 {
            itemTwo += 1
        }


        myText.text = """
        selecteer de \(imagesArray[itemOne].capitalized)
        voor dat je de \(imagesArray[itemTwo].capitalized) selecteert
        """
    }

    //Mark: setup images and randomizeing
    fileprivate func setupImages() {
        imageOne.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[itemOne])
        imageTwo.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[itemTwo])
    }


    //MARK: Button Randomizer
    @IBAction func nextBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        setupQuestions()
        setupImages()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //Get image stringvalue to compare it with the question array
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
self.myImageView.image = UIImage(myImageArray[0])
self.myImageView.tag = 0
```

then inside touches

```
myImageArray[self.myImageView.tag]
```

you can also declare a var for a good pattern following

---

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   print("itemOne name \(myImageArray[itemOne]) , itemTwo name \(myImageArray[itemTwo])")
}
```

Comment: actually i'm using arc4random with an upper bound of my myImageArray.count

Comment: It's best to avoid tag values of `0` since that is the default tag value for all views.

Comment: you can do what you need but use the new https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527565/5820010 random generation

Comment: @rmaddy yes , i added for illustration in case he will change it later for another value