# does updating images in Firebase will take storage every time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

i want to save 10 images in Firebase.
and update that 10 images with another 10 images everyday,
does updating the images will take storage every time?

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.  It always helps to show code and explain fully the behavior of that code.

Comment: I think, it depends on the preferences of the web site, updates may or may not take extra storage. Just for example; Google Drive —though you upload same file with exactly the same file name— can store different versions of the same file. You'd better dig into the settings of the Firebase docs.

Answer (score 0):

Every distinct file in Firebase Storage has its own unique path.

If you store one of your images at `/my-images/5` and then upload a different image to the same resource path (`/my-images/5`), it will get overwritten replacing the currently stored one.

Answering your question: no, it won't take any additional storage capacity (ignoring the difference in size between the old and the new file) provided that you upload your images to the same locations.

[Similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450700/firebase-storage-overwriting-files)