# Override name of firebase storage file before downloading it?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm working on a "google drive"-like functionality in my app and stuck with the "rename a file" functionality: because firebase storage is run on google cloud and google cloud doesn't have a "rename" function this task appeared to be not that obvious to solve. (they have a "move" command which is too heavy for the rename as it first copies and then deletes a file)

However I store "descriptor" object in a firestore for every file. Among other data, that descriptor stores the filename which I use to display to users.

The only reason I was looking for an option to rename the file in the storage itself is because my users have an option to download each file - in this case the file name comes from the storage itself and I can't find a way to change it.

For this, I generate a link like below that user clicks to download a file:

```
<a href="https://...myurl.com/..path_to_file/Hook.docx?..token-here..." download="Hook111.docx" target="_blank"></a>
```

It appeared that the `download` parameter is [ignored by browsers if server returns the name in header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23873370/1713920)

So I was hoping to update the name in storage using metadata of the file:

```
bucket.file(".../Hook.docx").setMetadata({name:"Hook11122.docx"})
```

but I'm getting this error

> Error: Value 'Hook11122.docx' in content does not agree with value
> 'users/Corp9wBL7BSHMgQf4mMnOyS31mD3/drive/BkkS0TbJMCxPUR9uHb2A_Hook.docx'.
> This can happen when a value set through a parameter is inconsistent
> with a value set in the request.

There are probably other solutions to this problem, but is there a way to tell firebase storage to return a different/custom name when downloading a file from a link?

Comment: You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450700/firebase-storage-overwriting-files) which is a similar issue.