# How to shift Array.count result by -1 using Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array with 7 objects inside it, and am using the `Array.count` to get the number of objects inside the array.

I'm then using `Int.random(in: 0 ... arrayMax)` to get a random object from the array. Yet, because there are 7 objects in the array, and the `.count` will return 7, I'll every once in a while get an error, because `7` is obviously `6`.

I've tried to solve this by going like this:

```
let nTMax = Array.count
let nTSelection = Int.random(in: 0 ... nTMax)
print (nTMax, nTSelection) 
let nTSelectionProtect = nTSelection -1
```

but the `nTSelectionProtect` refuses to be accepted. I was hoping to do a safety calculation so that 7 will always be 6, but I'm not sure how to do it.

How would I do it?

Comment: Why do this `let nTSelectionProtect = nTSelection -1` if you can produce a valid value from correct range also `nTSelection` may be zer0 so `nTSelectionProtect` will be `-1`

Comment: Note:  there is a `randomElement()` call on array that will return an element.  It is optional, so: `if element = array.randomElement() { // use the element }`.

Comment: @vacawama thanks, I'll try to modify my code and see if it works!

Comment: @vacawama unfortunately all i got was an error: "1. Overloads for 'subscript' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Int), (Range<Int>), (Range<Self.Index>), ((UnboundedRange_) -> ())"

Comment: `randomElement()` gives you a random element from your array, not the index of that element

Comment: see all possible ways here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-apples-swift-language

Comment: you can do `guard let ele = arr.ranomElement() , let index = arr.index(of:ele) else { return  }`

Comment: @vacawama weirdly enough, I can't use let nTeslaUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: nTeslaQuoteArray.randomElement()) because it will just output an error `Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'` and `Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'` and `Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'`

Comment: It returns an optional element which needs to be unwrapped: `nTeslaUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: nTeslaQuoteArray.randomElement() ?? "")`

Comment: `arr.indices` will return the range you need to generate a random index:  `let nTSelection = Int.random(in: arr.indices)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more safe to use

```
    let nTSelection = Int.random(in: 0..<nTMax)
```

---

This

```
    let nTSelectionProtect = nTSelection -1
```

will crash if the random returned is zero, this `nTSelection -1` will be `-1`

---

You can also fetch a random element with

```
print(array.randomElement())
```

Comment: And this is why `.indices` exists, and why you should seldom write `0..<arr.count`.

Comment: @Alexander i'm clarifying reason of the crash , no need for `Random` / `indices` at alll , `randomElemnt` will do the job

Comment: Yep, although in some cases you need a random index (such as for setting an element, not retrieving), for which `a.indices.randomElement()` can be useful.