# Firestore get random document with where condition

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've read this link [Firestore: How to get random documents in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection) but it looks like my problem is different. Because these solutions are not good for queries with where conditions.

My collection looks like this:

[image]

I have 140K documents in this collection. **I want to get random X amount of documents filtered by any category.**

My code looks like this (Swift):

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("quotes")
    .whereField("categories", arrayContainsAny: ['change'])
    .limit(to: 25)
```

This code always returns the same documents. **How can I get random documents filtered by category?**

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection, and can it be applied to your use-case?

Comment: No it covers no where condition situations.

Comment: Did you try adding your condition the queries that are shown in that answer? What didn't work about it when you did that?

Comment: Hi @TolgayToklar, you could also use `placeId` as reference to your query.
First, you should create a function that generates a random number. You may refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007129/how-does-one-generate-a-random-number-in-swift) for generating random number. Add this `.whereField("placeId", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: randomNumber)` to your query after getting a random number. This will randomize getting documents from Firestore based on the random number you generated and the placeId of your documents. Let me know if this can be applied to your use-case.

Comment: No it cannot because categories are not equally placed. Let’s say: you created a random number and it is 10. And you need to get a document from “Life” category. But all documents that contains “Life” category’s placeId less than 10. Firestore will return 0 document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Frank, the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection) has everything you need. You can chain the where conditions.

After following the steps, you can query like:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("quotes")
    .whereField("categories", arrayContainsAny: ['change'])
    .whereField("random", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: random)
    .limit(to: 25)
```

**edit** ahhh I see your point. I would work around this issue by querying again.

- if the result is less than what's needed (25) run another query, something like

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("quotes")
    .whereField("categories", arrayContainsAny: ['change'])
    .whereField("random", isLessThan: random)
    .limit(to: 25)
```

You can then store some of the results of both queries to get your 25

Comment: No it cannot because categories are not equally placed. Let’s say: you created a random number and it is 10. And you need to get a document from “Life” category. But all documents that contains “Life” category’s placeId less than 10. Firestore will return 0 document

Comment: @TolgayToklar I see you point, check my edit. Would that work? probably not the best since you will have to query again...?

Comment: Yeah, I guess this would work. I am gonna try and let you know :)