# Could not find an overload "init' that accept the supplied argument

Tags: ios, swift, int, arc4random, uint32

```
var x = jokes[arc4random_uniform(UInt32(jokes.count))]
```

Why does this line of code produce such error?

When this code is written

```
var x = jokes[Int(arc4random()%jokes.count)]
```

This error appear

```
Int is not convertible to UInt32
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crash when casting the result of arc4random() to Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087518/crash-when-casting-the-result-of-arc4random-to-int)

Comment: Needless to say, this is not obviated by the new `random` methods, e.g. `let joke = jokes.randomElement()` (or `let joke = jokes[.random(in: 0..<jokes.count)]` or `let joke = jokes[jokes.indices.randomElement()]` or ...). These all enjoy the unbiased random number akin to `arc4_random_uniform`, but with swiftier syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array subscript takes an `Int`, not a `UInt32`. You need to convert back:

```
let x = jokes[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(jokes.count)))]
```

If this gets a bit noisy for you, you may want to create a function to handle it:

```
func randomValueLessThan(x: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(x)))
}
```

Or you could extend Array to help out:

```
extension Array {
    func uniformSelection() -> T {
        return self[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))]
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: It is worth digging a little deeper into the `Int(arc4random()%jokes.count)` case because you might be tempted to fix it incorrectly, and it demonstrates why Swift works the way it does.

Let's start with your version

```
let n = Int(arc4random() % jokes.count)
// => Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

That's a little confusing. Let's simplify to see the problem

```
let n = arc4random() % jokes.count
// => Cannot invoke '%' with an argument list of type '(UInt32, Int)'
```

That should be clearer. `arc4random` returns a `UInt32` and `jokes.count()` returns an `Int`. You can't modulus different types. You need to get them to the same place. Well, we want an `Int`, right? Seems easy:

```
let n = Int(arc4random()) % jokes.count   // WARNING!!!! Never ever do this!!!!
```

Why is Apple so pedantic and forces us to do that by hand? Couldn't the compiler just cast it automatically? Well, the above code will work fine on a 64-bit processor and crash about half the time on a 32-bit processor. That's because by calling `Int()`, you're promising that the value will *always* be in the `Int` range. And on a 32-bit processor, that's the 32-bit signed range. But `arc4random` returns a value in the whole 32-bit *unsigned* range, which includes lots of numbers that won't fit in an `Int`. Blam! (Or if you turn off bounds checking, then it just trashes your numbers like it does in C, which is no better.)

That's why Swift is picky about integer conversions. You need to be absolutely certain when you convert that it's a safe conversion. You shouldn't just sprinkle them around until it compiles.

That said, of course you should never use modulus on `arc4random`. [But that's a different question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640624/arc4random-modulu-biased)

As one more side note, you'll notice that the numeric casting in `randomValueLessThan()` creates many possible invalid situations. If you pass a number less than 0 you'll crash (that shouldn't be surprising, though). If you pass a number greater than `UInt32.Max`, you'll also crash, which is slightly more surprising, but pretty unlikely in most code. The point of this is that by adding these casts, we've made `randomValueLessThan` a *partial function*. It's not defined over all of its range of inputs (it's "domain"). In "real life" programming, we do that all the time and we just hope it never bites us. But Swift is trying to help us get bitten even less by making it more obvious when you're breaking type safety.

`uniformSelection` has a similar problem. It's only defined for arrays with fewer than `UInt32.Max` elements. These sometimes feel like meaningless corner cases, and they are, until suddenly they aren't and your program crashes. (`Array.subscript` is also a partial function, since it is undefined for values outside the array's range. I actually suggested to Apple that `Array.subscript` return an optional to account for that. They were probably wise to ignore me.)

Comment: can you add answer for arc4random as well using modulus

Comment: You should never use `arc4random` with modulus. That biases your values. The reason the compiler fails, though is the same. You must explicitly convert values between `Int` and `UInt32`.

Comment: (I'll add a bit more on that, though. It's an educational point.)

Comment: @MartinR Fixed. I meant array subscript.

Comment: Another good thread about the "modulo bias": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator.